# Managing green threads

Tags: multithreading, task, rust, green-threads

To use the `M:N` threading model in Rust, I would get a pool going and just start spawning tasks as usual.  [The Green Documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/green/index.html) gives the following example:

```
#![feature(phase)]
#[phase(plugin)] extern crate green;

green_start!(main)

fn main() {
    // Running inside a green pool

    // Spawn more green threads?
    for x in some_thing.iter() {
        spawn(proc() {
            some_task()
        });
    }
}
```

If you wanted to dynamically add another OS thread, one would do something like this:

```
extern crate green;
extern crate rustuv;

use std::task::TaskBuilder;
use green::{SchedPool, PoolConfig, GreenTaskBuilder};

let mut config = PoolConfig::new();

// Optional: Set the event loop to be rustuv's to allow I/O to work
config.event_loop_factory = rustuv::event_loop;

let mut pool = SchedPool::new(config);

// Spawn tasks into the pool of schedulers
TaskBuilder::new().green(&mut pool).spawn(proc() {
    // this code is running inside the pool of schedulers

    spawn(proc() {
        // this code is also running inside the same scheduler pool
    });
});

// Dynamically add a new scheduler to the scheduler pool. This adds another
// OS thread that green threads can be multiplexed on to.
let mut handle = pool.spawn_sched();

// Pin a task to the spawned scheduler
TaskBuilder::new().green_pinned(&mut pool, &mut handle).spawn(proc() {
    /* ... */
});

// Handles keep schedulers alive, so be sure to drop all handles before
// destroying the sched pool
drop(handle);

// Required to shut down this scheduler pool.
// The task will fail if `shutdown` is not called.
pool.shutdown();
```

Is there a way to say use x num of OS threads, or do they have to be created and managed within the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`PoolConfig`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/green/struct.PoolConfig.html), the number of OS threads can be specified when creating a new pool :

```
let mut config = PoolConfig::new();
config.threads = 42u;
let mut pool = SchedPool::new(config);
// use your pool with 42 OS threads as you want
```

The default value of `config.threads` is given by [`std::rt::default_sched_threads()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rt/fn.default_sched_threads.html)